# what is the difference between collect statistics multi column or single column in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

```
collect statistics column(column1,column2,column3) on table ;
and 
collect statistics column(column1) on table ;
collect statistics column(column2) on table ;
collect statistics column(column3) on table ;
```

What is the difference in both ways of collecting stats and what are the pros and cons of both in teradata?

Comment: https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Collect-Stats-Multi-Column/m-p/63087

Comment: if we have to chose from both of the situations what should better option?

Comment: @RakshitSakhuja - It depends. You haven’t provided enough information about the table or the query patterns that access this table. You may find it necessary to have both sets of statistics in order for the optimizer to build efficient queries.

Answer (score 2):

In your frequently performed queries if you are using column1,column2 and column3 in the search condition together, then it is better to take stats jointly. `It will permit the Optimizer to estimate more accurately  the number of qualifying rows for queries that specify  these columns.` And if Indexes are defined for these column set. Then Teradata treat Multicolumn stats as index stats.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of collecting statistics is to help the Optimizer prepare more efficient query plans.  Collecting stats provides info like # unique values, rows per value, etc.  If the Optimizer knows how many rows it has to deal with in each step, then it generate a more accurate and efficient query plan.

This query accesses the table data via a single column:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE column1 = 'James Bond'
```

Only the single column statistics would help here, since we'd know approximately how many rows to expect.  The multi-column stats are of no use, since it provides info for the column group (column1, column2, column3).

One way to test it, is to run an EXPLAIN on your queries.  Check the before/after plans and see how collecting the different stats affects the row estimates.